# How to direct the stream of an audio file through express.js if it is on another server

Tags: node.js, express, axios, telegram-bot

I have a handler express.js which takes as input the ID of the file.

And I don't know how to catch the stream of this file through for example axios and transfer it to the client part SPA.

Thank for your attention

```js
router.get('/api/track/:id', async(req, res) => {
  // Create bot
  const telegram = new Telegram(token, { agent })
  const fileId = req.params.id

  let url
  try {
    // Getting filelink from telegram
    url = await telegram.getFileLink(fileId)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error on getting link on file from telegram', error)
    return { message: 'Error on getting link on file from telegram', code: 4, error}
  }
  
  res.set('content-type', 'audio/mp3');
  res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');
  
  // And this is place i'm try download file as stream...
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    })
  
    console.log(response)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 5):

The express `res` object is a **writable** stream. That means you can pipe the axios **readable** response stream into the express **writable** response stream.

```js
const response = await axios({
  url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'stream'
})

console.log(response)
response.data.pipe(res)
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, please? I'm obviously doing something wrong and I have an error. (read ECONNRESET
[0]     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27))

Comment: There's nothing else to it, really. They're just streams so you could read up on how those work. Are you sure the other server is working?

Comment: Hm, maybe. In my country telegram blocked and i connect on the proxy. Anyway thank you. I try this solution in my home again.

Comment: anyway, I can’t understand how to transfer this stream to the client. I clearly did not understand something.

Comment: That's what this line of code does `response.data.pipe(res)`.

Comment: bro, i'm realy idiot. i full week thought where my problem. And today i found it. In the axios im not using proxy.....

Comment: I've been working on a task for a couple of hours, and this saved my life. Thank you so much